Can I capture warning messages into a log file during executing pybel?
Context
I need to convert thousands of SMILES into SDF file using pybel via python scripts (several code lines below).
for ind, row in df.iterrows():
      df.loc[ind, 'ROMol'] = pybel.readstring("smi", row[args.smi_column])
      df.loc[ind, 'ROMol'].make3D(steps=args.pybel_steps)

During the progress, I observe a lot of warning/errors messages directly shown on my terminal although pybel returns a full list of converted molecules.
For examples,
*** Open Babel Warning  in CorrectStereoAtoms
  Could not correct 3 stereocenter(s) in this molecule ()
  with Atom Ids as follows: 9 12 16
==============================
*** Open Babel Warning  in CorrectStereoAtoms
  Could not correct 3 stereocenter(s) in this molecule ()
  with Atom Ids as follows: 2 3 14

Problem
I would like to further investigate pybel warnings/errors in order to fix my converted molecules if needed. In the initial stages, I have to capture or redirect them with inputted SMILES into a log file. However, I have not found any approaches to overcome the issue.
Please help me to solve this. Thank you very much.
Additional context
I have conducted a research, however I have not reach solutions. Please help me to do this.
There are some links:
redirect-logs-to-file-in-pybel
can-i-capture-warning-messages-during-format-conversion-in-pybel
how-to-disable-logged-warnings-in-pybel

Are you running on some kind of (l)inux? If so redirection of standard out/error, or the tee or script commands may be solutions, amongst many others. But this is really a programming question, and you''ll probably  get better help on an appropriate programming forum.

Yes, I run my python script on Linux-based OS. Because I have researched in some coding forums such as Github.com (ask directly to authors) and stackoverflow.com, there are no available instructions. Thus, I asked here and hope reach a suitable solution. Some links I reached are 1 2

Assuming you are doing everything interactively script is probably easiest. See for example https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/script-command-in-linux-with-examples/

@IanBush Thank you for your suggestion. I tried script and it works well. However, if I would like to integrate some codes into my python script, how could I do? Let me explain more: I want to extract only SMILES strings which have Open Babel warnings instead of everything printed in sys.stdout like what script does.

Please ask on a programming forum and not through a comment. This is not about Chemistry, and so this is not the appropriate place.
